# vim persistent undo is not working properly

Tags: vim, undo, persistent

I am trying to use persistent undo with vim 7.4.9

In my vimrc, I have:

```
set undodir=/home/myname/.vim/undo//
set undofile
set undolevels=1000
set undoreload=10000
```

of course, /home/myname/.vim/undo directory exists.

I have opened a few files with vim and made a few changes.

I see undofiles created in /home/myname/.vim/undo/:

```
$ ll /home/myname/.vim/undo/
total 23K
-rw-r--r-- 1 hpcpcollab hpcpcollab  523 18 sept. 11:23 %home%myname%foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 hpcpcollab hpcpcollab  14K 18 sept. 11:03 %home%myname%bar
-rw-r--r-- 1 hpcpcollab hpcpcollab 2,2K 18 sept. 11:52 %home%myname%test
```

However, when I close these files, reopen them, and press 'u' in order to undo, vim replies: "Already at oldest change".

What am I missing?

Thx

Julien

Answer (score 3):

Could patch 7.4.24 perhaps fix your problem?
In any case, try explicitly reading the undofile using `:verbose :rundo ~/.vim/undo/undofile` and see what error Vim reports. This should help localize the problem, why vim doesn't use the undofile.

Comment: undo file read seems to be OK:

`Lecture du fichier d'annulations : /home/myname/.vim/undo/%home%myname%foo...
Fin de lecture du fichier d'annulations /home/myname/.vim/undo/%home%myname%foo
Appuyez sur ENTRÉE ou tapez une commande pour continuer`

(This is french for:
`Reading undo file /home/myname/.vim/undo/%home%myname%foo...
End or reading undo file /home/myname/.vim/undo/%home%myname%foo
Press ENTER or type a command to continue`

Comment: So undo file is correct, I can read it, then I can undo changes from a previous session.
Apparently the only issue is that this undo file is not read automatically at startup.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same configuration except for the `//` at the end of your `undodir` definition. Try to remove those. You can also try the `:undolist` command to see if vim actually read something.

May I suggest you use the [`Gundo`](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/) plugin to manage your undo tree ? It is one of the most powerful plugin I am using, and it offers a lot of features to manage undo / redo in vim.

Comment: How does any plugin help, if Vim itsself won't be reading the undofile?

Comment: @Christian : The plugin part was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason but you could use a workaround. Create an `autocommand` that reads the directory where you save the `undo` history just after loading the file to edit:

```
au FileReadPost * rundo /home/myname/.vim/undo
```

Comment: If loading of the undo-file fails, then this won't work as well. Besides `:rundo` is expecting an undofile to read from.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: You are right. It accepts a file but tested it with a directory like this and worked so I posted it. I will have to look at it more carefully. About the loading fail, I assume it won't ocurr if the path exists and its readable.